# Error message "option_id" when flagging a question on the iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I wanted to report [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168181/linking-village-problem) on Apple Stack Exchange as off topic, but when I tapped "flag" I get this error message:

[image: option_id]

I am using iOS 8.1.1 and the latest version of the Stack Exchange App (1.2.1)

Comment: Maybe it was closed while you were viewing it. Still a bug, message should be better.

Answer (score 1):

This question was caused by the question being closed while you were looking at it.  All the close options disappeared so the API could not find a matching option.

For a while the app has been displaying this message:

> The app submitted an invalid request. Please let us know on meta.

Now it will display either of the following depending on whether you started from Close or Flag:

> This close option is no longer available.  The question may have already been closed.

*or*

> This flag option is no longer available.